# Singular gradient erros, NLS in R

Tags: r, regression, optimization, error, nls

I'm trying to fit `nls(Mound~ a*kg.bag.collar^b + c, start = list(a = 83, b = -.5, c=100), data=test)` using the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RnWT6SgoL5-Aw60WEZkVKJT9kWaAbX3Z/view?usp=sharing) here. I've fit it without trouble without the c term with no problem. But adding the c term gives "Error in nls(mToMound.stand ~ a * as.numeric(kg.bag.collar)^b + c, start = list(a = 83,  : 
  singular gradient."
I know the error can mean that poor starting values are given, but I've tried a wide range, and more to the point, a and be here are very close to the estimates that come from the fit without "c" included. 
The subject-matter dictates that I need the c term to allow the possibility of a concave up decreasing function that doesn't go through the origin.

What are my options here? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You provide a `b` variable but it doesn't appear in the formula: typographical error?  As far as options go, you can help us out by describing your data: what is the range of values of `kg.bag.collar` and how many observations do you have?  Could you post a scatterplot of the (`kg.bag.collar`, `mound`) values?

Comment: Thanks, whuber. Yes. b missing was a typo. I added a scatterplot, which shows the range of each variable. There are 57 observations.

Comment: I don't think you can get a good fit with that model. You have pretty strong heteroscedasticity. In particular the variance at your low levels is high. This means the parameter estimate for `a` is quite uncertain. Your data also doesn't show a clear asymptote for large values yet. This means a parameter estimate for `c` would be quite uncertain. Finally, you can expect a strong covariance between these two parameters. In total, this makes for a challenging optimization problem.

Comment: This mean, if you can't assume `c` to be zero (or at least greater than zero), you need to get more data over a wider range of x values. Or maybe use a Bayesian approach if you have a good idea what to expect as a value for `c`.

Comment: @Roland The heteroscedasticity may be there, but it's not the cause of the problem.  There are two more-salient issues.  First, the starting values are *way* off.  Second, the intercept and the exponential terms are nearly collinear.  Together, these problems can cause any search routine to miss the global optimum altogether.  Ecologist: consider estimating starting values by setting `b` to a reasonable value (like -0.5) and fitting `a` and `c` using OLS (that is, `lm`).  Then apply nls.  You can deal with the heteroscedasticity later.

Comment: Hmm. @whuber, why do you say the starting values are way off? When I fit the model without a 'c' term I get 
y = 83.0063   * kg.bag.collar ^ -0.4977 with significant a and b.

Comment: All you have to do is plot the function $y= 83x^{-0.5} + 100$ and compare it to your scatterplot: the graph isn't anywhere near the points.  For instance, near $x=100$ your points range between $0$ and $15$ in height, but $y=83/\sqrt{100} + 100 = 108.3$ is far different from any of them.

Comment: Right. Thank you. For what it's worth, I do get the same singular gradient error when using slope and intercept from a lm as the starting values for 'a' and 'c'. I will try @Roland's solution shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get successful convergence by using the Golub-Pereyra algorithm for partially linear least-squares models (which is a more sophisticated way of doing what @whuber [suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409095/singular-gradient-erros-nls-in-r/409201#comment764459_409095)):

```
fit <- nls(mound~ cbind(1, kg.bag.collar^b), start = list(b = -.5),
             data=test, algorithm = "plinear")
plot(mound ~ kg.bag.collar, data = test)
curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(kg.bag.collar = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: resulting plot]

That looks somewhat reasonable but summary output shows that none of the parameters is significant (note that `.lin1` is the parameter c and `.lin2` is a).

```
summary(fit)
#Formula: mound ~ cbind(1, kg.bag.collar^b)
#
#Parameters:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#b       0.7857     1.1344   0.693   0.4915  
#.lin1  18.7878    10.5973   1.773   0.0819 .
#.lin2  -0.2737     1.7254  -0.159   0.8745  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 5.402 on 54 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.472e-06
```

If you use starting values close to this solution, the default Gauss-Newton algorithm also converges.

You have strong collinearity, which means there are more parameters in your model than your data supports:

```
vcov(fit)
#               b     .lin1      .lin2
#b       1.286925 -11.82171   1.956174
#.lin1 -11.821714 112.30234 -18.076169
#.lin2   1.956174 -18.07617   2.977021
```

You should try and collect more and better data if you need to fit this model (but that might not be possible).

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. This is helpful, in particular the G-P algorithm for finding starting values to use in the default G-N algorithm. I like the G-N algorithm because it allows me to use confint2 to get 95% CIs. 
Can you explain or point me to a resource to better understand what you mean by 'collinearity' in this context? I know the term with respect to >1 independent variable in a model being highly correlated (e.g., https://tinyurl.com/y25ld8ow), but I only have 1 predictor here (kg.bag.collar). I don't see any resources pointing to another meaning, either. Thanks again.